# How do I force JAXB to escape newline characters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, escaping, newline

I'm trying to use the JAXB marshaller to marshall objects that have newline characters in them, and I'd like it to escape these characters they same way it does for <, >, and carriage return. I imagine it's a just a switch but formatted output doesn't seem to help

The code I'm using

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class testesr {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {
        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TesterElement.class).createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        marshaller.marshal(new TesterElement(), new File("C:\\Temp\\temp.xml"));

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c START C:\\Temp\\temp.xml");
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class TesterElement {
        String valueWithCarriageReturn = "some\rvalue";
        String valueWithNewLine = "some\nvalue";
        String valueWithBoth = "some\r\nvalue";
        String otherCharacters = "some < | > value";

        public String getOtherCharacters() {
            return otherCharacters;
        }

        public void setOtherCharacters(String otherCharacters) {
            this.otherCharacters = otherCharacters;
        }

        public String getValueWithCarriageReturn() {
            return valueWithCarriageReturn;
        }

        public void setValueWithCarriageReturn(String valueWithCarriageReturn) {
            this.valueWithCarriageReturn = valueWithCarriageReturn;
        }

        public String getValueWithNewLine() {
            return valueWithNewLine;
        }

        public void setValueWithNewLine(String valueWithNewLine) {
            this.valueWithNewLine = valueWithNewLine;
        }

        public String getValueWithBoth() {
            return valueWithBoth;
        }

        public void setValueWithBoth(String valueWithBoth) {
            this.valueWithBoth = valueWithBoth;
        }
    }
}
```

produces this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testerElement>
    <otherCharacters>some &lt; | &gt; value</otherCharacters>
    <valueWithBoth>some&#xD;
value</valueWithBoth>
    <valueWithCarriageReturn>some&#xD;value</valueWithCarriageReturn>
    <valueWithNewLine>some
value</valueWithNewLine>
</testerElement>
```

But how do I make it print the new line characters to this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testerElement>
    <otherCharacters>some &lt; | &gt; value</otherCharacters>
    <valueWithBoth>some&#xD;&#xA;value</valueWithBoth>
    <valueWithCarriageReturn>some&#xD;value</valueWithCarriageReturn>
    <valueWithNewLine>some&#xA;value</valueWithNewLine>
</testerElement>
```

Comment: Why do you need JAXB to do that? Whitespace is perfectly valid within a tag value. Are you saying that all whitespace should be escaped or just newlines? In which case, what's so special about new lines?

Comment: I have a vendor that's sending me an XML request this way, and I'd like to return the response in the same format. I haven't noticed any other whitespace characters other than spaces, but I'd assume they treat tab the same way.

Comment: Is it a question of politeness or are you sure the vendor won't accept a non-escaped value? I'd suggest trying it 'as is' first before jumping through loads of hoops doing something non-standard.

Comment: When you say loads of hoops, how hard would this be? I had assumed it would be a preference, the way setting it to be formatted is.

Comment: I'm just not sure it's so easy. JAXB is designed for XML data binding and this isn't a function of data binding, the same data is represented whether you escape the characters or not. The only exceptions here are reserved characters such as '<' or '>' and you've not option about escaping them. The Formatted option is designed to make things more human readable and that's a specific need for diagnostics or anything which might be read by a human. XML is pretty well defined for machine-to-machine communication so it seems to me like *not* the kind of thing that would be an option.